# Event listener not passing all functions

Tags: javascript

```
let popup = document.getElementById("confirmation-message");
const errorMessage = document.getElementById('errorMessage');
const form = document.getElementById('orm');
const submitButton = document.getElementById('submit-button');
const choices = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('data_point'));

function submitForm() {
  // nothing is selected, show an error and don't submit
  if (choices.filter(function(input) {
      return input.checked;
    }).length === 0) {
    errorMessage.classList.add('show');
    return;
  }

  //log each datapoint 
  choices.forEach(function(input) {
    const customAttributeName = input.dataset.customAttributeName;
    const customAttributeValue = input.dataset.customAttributeValue;
    if (input.checked) {
      appboy.getUser().setCustomData(customDataName, customDataValue);
    }
  });

  appboy.requestDataFlush();
  appboy.closeMessage();
}
// hides for once submit button is clicked
function hideForm() {
  form.classList.add("hide");
}
// diplays a confirmation message once submit button is clicked
function openConfirmationMessage() {
  popup.classList.add("open-conf-message");
}

//closes confirmation message
function closeConfirmationMessage() {
  popup.classList.add("hide");
}

submitButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

  submitForm();
  hideForm();
  openConfirmationMessage();
});
```

Im looking for all three functions to run when the submit button is clicked. Even though all three functions are listed in the event listener the submitForm() function doesnt seem to be running, sice there is no error message that displays. Wasn't too sure if this is a syntax issue. The hideForm(); and openConfirmationMessage(); seem to be working just fine.

Comment: add your HTML to get the proper help

Comment: Aside: `if(choices.filter(...).length == 0)` is better written as `if (!choices.some(...))`

Comment: All 3 functions must be running. Add `console.log()` calls to each function to confirm.

Comment: If the submit button is in a form, it will submit the form and the page will reload.

Comment: How would you know whether it ran or not?